# Check file size on S3 without downloading?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have customer files uploaded to Amazon S3, and I would like to add a feature to count the size of those files for each customer. Is there a way to "peek" into the file size without downloading them? I know you can view from the Amazon control panel but I need to do it pro grammatically.

Comment: Have you tried a HEAD request instead of a GET?

Comment: Could you post what your `HEAD request` was, please?  I'm also trying to do this and am unsure how to do this

Comment: Check my answer below there's an easier way using the CLI.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Send an HTTP **HEAD** request to the object.  A HEAD request will retrieve the same HTTP headers as a GET request, but it will not retrieve the body of the object (saving you bandwidth).  You can then parse out the Content-Length header value from the HTTP response headers.

Comment: Check my answer below there's an easier way using the CLI.

Comment: It's important to note that only as of December 2020 Amazon has introduced a strongly consistent model for S3. Prior to that, an uploaded file to S3 was not necessarily immediately available, and a HEAD request could still fail even after the file has been uploaded (for an indeterministic amount of time)

Answer (score 61):

Node.js example:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

function sizeOf(key, bucket) {
    return s3.headObject({ Key: key, Bucket: bucket })
        .promise()
        .then(res => res.ContentLength);
}


// A test
sizeOf('ahihi.mp4', 'output').then(size => console.log(size));
```

Doc is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property).

Comment: Check my answer below there's an easier way using the CLI.

Comment: Getting size of the uploaded images thanks.

Answer (score 60):

You can simply use the `s3 ls` command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive --human-readable --summarize
```

Outputs

```
2013-09-02 21:37:53   10 Bytes a.txt
2013-09-02 21:37:53  2.9 MiB foo.zip
2013-09-02 21:32:57   23 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/a
2013-09-02 21:32:58   41 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/b
2013-09-02 21:32:57  281 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/c
2013-09-02 21:32:57   73 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/d
2013-09-02 21:32:57  452 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/e
2013-09-02 21:32:57  896 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/hooks/bar
2013-09-02 21:32:57  189 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/hooks/foo
2013-09-02 21:32:57  398 Bytes z.txt

Total Objects: 10
   Total Size: 2.9 MiB
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html

Answer (score 9):

This is a solution for whoever is using Java and the S3 Java library provided by Amazon.

If you are using `com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3` you can use a `GetObjectMetadataRequest` request which allows you to query the object length.

The libraries you have to use are:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.511</version>
</dependency>
```

Imports:

```java
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;
```

And the code you need to get the *content length*:

```java
GetObjectMetadataRequest metadataRequest = new GetObjectMetadataRequest(bucketName, fileName);
final ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = s3Client.getObjectMetadata(metadataRequest);
long contentLength = objectMetadata.getContentLength();
```

Before you can execute the code above, you will need to build the S3 client. Here is some example code for that:

```java
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            accessKey,
            secretKey
);
s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(clientRegion)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Michael's advice, my successful code looked like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

file_url = MyObject.first.file.url

url = URI.parse(file_url)
req = Net::HTTP::Head.new url.path
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}

file_length = res["content-length"]
```

Answer (score 6):

I do something like this in Python to get the cumulative size of all files under a given prefix:

```python
import boto3

bucket = 'your-bucket-name'
prefix = 'some/s3/prefix/'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

size = 0

result = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
size += sum([x['Size'] for x in result['Contents']])

while result['IsTruncated']:
    result = s3.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix,
        ContinuationToken=result['NextContinuationToken'])
    size += sum([x['Size'] for x in result['Contents']])

print('Total size in MB: ' + str(size / (1000**2)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't that final line be MB , not Mb.  As the size returned by ['Size'] is in Bytes, not bits ?

Comment: Actually, shouldn't be `2**20` instead of `1000**2`?

Answer (score 5):

[.NET AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/)
---- [ListObjectsRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TListObjectsRequest.html), [ListObjectsResponse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TListObjectsResponse.html), [S3Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3Object.html)

```cs
AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
SpaceUsed(s3, "putBucketNameHere");

static void SpaceUsed(AmazonS3Client s3Client, string bucketName)
    {
        ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
        request.BucketName = bucketName;
        ListObjectsResponse response = s3Client.ListObjects(request);
        long totalSize = 0;
        foreach (S3Object o in response.S3Objects)
        {
            totalSize += o.Size;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total Size of bucket " + bucketName + " is " +
            Math.Round(totalSize / 1024.0 / 1024.0, 2) + " MB");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to do this with a single file, you can use [`aws s3api head-object`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html) to get the metadata only without downloading the file itself:

```
$ aws s3api head-object --bucket mybucket --key path/to/myfile.csv --query "ContentLength"
```

**Explanation**

- `s3api head-object` retrieves the object metadata in json format
- `--query "ContentLength"` filters the json response to get the size of the body in bytes

Comment: Also we can do it without jq command: aws s3api head-object --bucket sdaunekotask2 --key test.html --query "ContentLength"

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a listing of the contents of the bucket. The metadata in the listing contains the file sizes of all of the objects. This is how it's implemented in the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp).

Answer (score 1):

## Android Solution

Integrate [aws sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html) and you get a pretty much straight forward solution:

```
// ... put this in background thread
List<S3ObjectSummary> s3ObjectSummaries;
s3ObjectSummaries = s3.listObjects(registeredBucket).getObjectSummaries();
for (int i = 0; i < s3ObjectSummaries.size(); i++) {
    S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary = s3ObjectSummaries.get(i);
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: size " + s3ObjectSummary.getSize());
}
```

- Here is a link to the official [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html#getSize()).
- Very important to execute the code in AsyncTask or any means to get you in a background thread, otherwise you get an exception for running network on ui thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is better solution.

```
$info = $s3->getObjectInfo($yourbucketName, $yourfilename);
print $info['size'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The following python code will provide the size of top 1000 files printing them individually from s3:

```js
import boto3

bucket = 'bucket_name'
prefix = 'prefix'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
contents = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket,  MaxKeys=1000, Prefix=prefix)['Contents']

for c in contents:
    print('Size (KB):', float(c['Size'])/1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aws C++ solution to get file size

```
//! Step 1: create s3 client
Aws::S3::S3Client s3Client(cred, config); //!Used cred & config,You can use other options.

//! Step 2: Head Object request
Aws::S3::Model::HeadObjectRequest headObj;
headObj.SetBucket(bucket);
headObj.SetKey(key);

//! Step 3: read size from object header metadata
auto object = s3Client.HeadObject(headObj);
if (object.IsSuccess())
{
    fileSize = object.GetResultWithOwnership().GetContentLength();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Head Object error: "
        << object .GetError().GetExceptionName() << " - "
        << object .GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
}
```

Note: Do not use GetObject to extract size, It reads file to extract information.

Comment: It didn't work for me with HeadObject, I had to use GetObject. But this answer is useful for C++ users.

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby** solution with *head_object*:

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region:               'us-east-1',     #or any other region
  access_key_id:        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secret_access_key:    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

res = s3.head_object(bucket: bucket_name, key: object_key)
file_size = res[:content_length]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is a private one, we can get the header by SDK.

PHP example:

```
$head = $client->headObject(
 [
   'Bucket' => $bucket,
   'Key' => $key,
 ]
);
$result = (int) ($head->get('ContentLength') ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in Java AWS SDK v2.x

Hope this helps.

```
Region region = Region.EU_CENTRAL_1;
        S3Client s3client = S3Client.builder().region(region).build();

        String bucket = "s3-demo";

        HeadObjectRequest headObjectRequest = HeadObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucket)
                .key(fileName)
                .build();
        HeadObjectResponse headObjectResponse = s3client.headObject(headObjectRequest);
        fileSize = headObjectResponse.contentLength();
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP code to check s3 object size (or any other object headers), notice the use [stream_context_set_default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php) to make sure it only uses a HEAD request

```
stream_context_set_default(
            array(
                'http' => array(
                    'method' => 'HEAD'
                )
            )
        );

$headers = get_headers('http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename.jpg', 1);
$headers = array_change_key_case($headers); 

$size = trim($headers['content-length'],'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Golang example, same principle, run head request again the object in question:

```
func returnKeySizeInMB(bucketName string, key string) {
    output, err := svc.HeadObject(
        &s3.HeadObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
            Key:    aws.String(key),
        })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to to send head request to item %q, %v", e.Detail.RequestParameters.Key, err)
    }

    return int(*output.ContentLength / 1024 / 1024)
}
```

Here, the parameter `key` means the path to the file.

For eg, if the URI of the file is `S3://my-personal-bucket/folder1/subfolder1/myfile.pdf`, then the syntax would look like:

```
output, err := svc.HeadObject(
        &s3.HeadObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String("my-personal-bucket"),
            Key:    aws.String("folder1/subfolder1/myfile.pdf"),
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

These days you could also use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) which gives you:

> Size – The object size in bytes.