# Is it possible to get S3 file size using Gaufrette?

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, gaufrette

I read this question so I know how to get the size without KnpGaufretteBundle but I'm wondering if there's a way to use it. I can't find anything on the Adapter classes.

[Check file size on S3 without downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910071/check-file-size-on-s3-without-downloading)

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The S3 adapters don't implement the `SizeCalculator` interface. But you may want to create a pull request improving them, so the adapter would do a HEAD request to the object to retrieve the `Content-Length`.