# Get filesizes from AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, size

Hi I need a way to get size of individual key in a bucket with specific prefix.
I want to search for a file that is smaller than some threshold. What would be the most efficient way to do it? I will need to execute this numerous times per day.

Comment: You can use a HEAD request (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html ) to retrieve metadata for a file

Answer (score 0):

This link has good info - [Check file size on S3 without downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910071/check-file-size-on-s3-without-downloading)

To do this in an automated fashion you can either write it as a Bash script and schedule it via Crontab on your own server or use the AWS SDK in your preferred language on Lambda and then schedule it via CloudWatch Events using a Cron task.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Answer (score 0):

if you mount the bucket prefix with something like [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys/), you can use find(1) to find the files you want:

```
$ find /mnt/s3bucket -size -1048576c
```