# How do I find the exact number of bytes of my AWS S3 bucket using AWS CLI?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

This thread: [How do I find the total size of my AWS S3 storage bucket or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192391/how-do-i-find-the-total-size-of-my-aws-s3-storage-bucket-or-folder) describes how to get the total filesize in an S3 bucket, but the result is not byte level accurate. I would need to know the exact number of bytes in the bucket.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57047462/8565438) confirms my own observation, that the command

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://bucket-name/
```

is not giving an output which is has byte level accuracy (tested it, and example output also confirms this). Similar advice is given [here](https://serverfault.com/a/721197/565536), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41252726/8565438) and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1006450/565536).

This thread: [Check file size on S3 without downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910071/check-file-size-on-s3-without-downloading) describes a way which could be used, but provides no code.

The bucket is around half a terabyte with a few tens of thousands of files. It is just a one-off thing, I do not have to do this frequently.

Comment: How big, how many objects is in the bucket? Do you have to do it frequently, or it is a one-off thing to check the size?

Comment: Thanks you, good questions! I added the answers to these to the question (last line).

Comment: There is s3 bucket size metric in CloudWatch. Did you check it?

Comment: I haven't, but good idea, thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you verify that this works for you, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know yet, I don't work on weekends. Next week I'll find out :)

Comment: So how did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [BucketSizeBytes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html) metric in CloudWatch. For more granual size information you can request [S3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use the same command but without the "human-readable" flag, then it will show size in bytes:

```
aws s3 ls --summarize --recursive s3://bucket-name/
```

From the [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/ls.html):

> --human-readable (boolean) Displays file sizes in human readable format.